# How to find type and size of content of a filegroup in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filegroup

I have a database using two filegroups. Let's call them PRIMARY and FG1. All data was originally in PRIMARY and then moved to be in FG1. This was achieved by moving the clustered indexes to FG1. The other indexes were removed and recreated without specifying a file group, but FG1 was defined as default so they are now effectively in FG1.

However, the file for PRIMARY still gets filled over time.

How can I find the type of stuff that remains in PRIMARY, including its size?
My goal is to get really everything over to FG1 so that PRIMARY doesn't get filled anymore.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/01/sql-server-list-all-objects-created-on-all-filegroups-in-database/ or http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c7483555-cc22-4f6c-b9c4-90811eb3bdb6

Comment: I had already found this sqlauthority.com entry and also executed the script there. But all that it lists is already in filegroup FG1. There must be something more...

Comment: Your second link seems like a very good start! It indeed found a clustered index on PRIMARY with lots of data. The same index (same table, same name) is already on FG1. How can that be? How do I move this over?

Comment: I suppose you already know this  : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175905.aspx ? Something strange, it states : `If a table has a clustered index, moving the clustered index to a new filegroup moves the table to that filegroup`

Comment: Maybe look at this, there's a point on duplicated clustered indexes whild changing filegroups : http://saveadba.blogspot.ch/2012/02/move-clustered-index-new-filegroup.html

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus The problem is with the LOB data which isn't moved when you recreate the clustered index in another filegroup. Could you please post this script from technet as an answer rather than comment so that I can mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus And regards from Fribourg by the way ;-)

Comment: bof, un lien n'est pas une réponse, alors tu peux mettre la réponse et accepter la tienne, tant qu'à faire ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script which lists all objects and all indexes in all filegroups:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c7483555-cc22-4f6c-b9c4-90811eb3bdb6

```
-- List all Objects and Indexes 
-- per Filegroup / Partition and Allocation Type 
-- including the allocated data size 
SELECT DS.name AS DataSpaceName 
  ,AU.type_desc AS AllocationDesc 
  ,AU.total_pages / 128 AS TotalSizeMB 
  ,AU.used_pages / 128 AS UsedSizeMB 
  ,AU.data_pages / 128 AS DataSizeMB 
  ,SCH.name AS SchemaName 
  ,OBJ.type_desc AS ObjectType       
  ,OBJ.name AS ObjectName 
  ,IDX.type_desc AS IndexType 
  ,IDX.name AS IndexName 
FROM sys.data_spaces AS DS 
 INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS AU 
     ON DS.data_space_id = AU.data_space_id 
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS PA 
     ON (AU.type IN (1, 3)  
         AND AU.container_id = PA.hobt_id) 
        OR 
        (AU.type = 2 
         AND AU.container_id = PA.partition_id) 
 INNER JOIN sys.objects AS OBJ 
     ON PA.object_id = OBJ.object_id 
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS SCH 
     ON OBJ.schema_id = SCH.schema_id 
 LEFT JOIN sys.indexes AS IDX 
     ON PA.object_id = IDX.object_id 
        AND PA.index_id = IDX.index_id 
ORDER BY DS.name 
    ,SCH.name 
    ,OBJ.name 
    ,IDX.name
```

Thanks @Raphaël Althaus for the link in the comments on the question.

Regarding the second point in my question I couldn't move the remaining objects from PRIMARY as it is LOB data. According to the documentation of [CREATE TABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), "the storage of any large column data specified in CREATE TABLE cannot be subsequently altered." Bad luck.

Comment: Old answer, but I just would like to clarify: You *can* move the data, but you have to do it by creating a temporary table on the new filegroup with the TEXTIMAGE_ON option set to that filegroup, then insert the data to that table, drop the old table, and rename your temp table to the old table name. This is how SQL server data tools does it.

Comment: @n-west Thanks for the suggestion. But what about foreign keys etc? You could drop and re-create them, but how do you guarantee the values with identity columns? It was too much a hassle so I still live with this situation.

Comment: For identity columns, just use Identity Insert: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx