# How to enumerate all the objects belonging to a file group using SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to enumerate all the objects belonging to a file group using SQL query?

I can look up the `SSMS > Object Explorer > Properties > Storage` on the each table and other objects to see what file group they belong to, but it might not be a feasible solution with hundreds of objects in the database.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @SeanLange I want to list all the objects (like tables, indexes etc) that are stored on a particular file group in a database. How can I do it using a SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find type and size of content of a filegroup in SQL server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000044/how-to-find-type-and-size-of-content-of-a-filegroup-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/01/sql-server-list-all-objects-created-on-all-filegroups-in-database/

```
SELECT o.[name], o.[type], i.[name], i.[index_id], f.[name] FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups f
ON i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o
ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id] WHERE i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
AND o.type = 'U' -- User Created Tables
```

You can alter the o.type to control what object types get returned.